# Can you programatically execute 'Run Custom Tool' on a ProjectItem in C#?

Tags: c#, vsx

I was wondering if it is possible to execute 'Run Custom Tool' on a file in the VS Solution? I have the ProjectItem object already.

info: C#, Visual Studio 2010 SDK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to ensure that the ProjectItem is selected, and then run:

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Project.RunCustomTool")
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to case the `Object` property value of a `ProjectItem` to a `VSProjectItem`. If not null, simply call RunCustomTool() on it.

```
// assumes you already have a ProjectItem projectItem that is **NOT** null
VSProjectItem vsProjectItem = projectItem.Object as VSProjectItem;
if (vsProjectItem != null)
{
    vsProjectItem.RunCustomTool();
}
```

Comment: you are correct, but your post is rather short. (Having known you personally, I ecpected better)